# Passing a variable to other page and execute a if condition function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a javascript function that is passing the value of a variable to other page, after a button is clicked.
It seams to pass the value partialy but something is wrong as my conditional compare function isnt working.

First page:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="pass(2)"></a>
<script>
function pass(x){
        var somval = x;
        window.location = 'contact/index.php?somval=' + somval;
    }

</script>
```

Second page:

```
<script>
var somval;
    var qsParm = new Array();
    function qs() {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var parms = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i < parms.length; i++) {
        var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
        if (pos > 0) {
            var key = parms[i].substring(0, pos);
            var val = parms[i].substring(pos + 1);
            qsParm[key] = val;
        }
    }
    }

    function compare(){
        if(somval == 1){
            alert(1);
            $("#radio_1").prop("checked", true);
        }else if(somval == 2){
            alert(2);
            $("#radio_2").prop("checked", true);
        }else{
        };
    }
    compare();
</script>
```

The only error displayed on console is: undefined index.php?somval=1:352

Comment: What do you mean by partially and where are you calling compare function from?

Comment: where you are calling qs function,seems there is no function call

Comment: its being called with compare();

Comment: compare(); works pefectly if I declare somval with a value on the last page, I updated the question with the errors.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not correct. You must initialise the **qaParm** variable as Object. Also set the value of the variable **someval** correctly. Kindly try the following code.

```
<script>
var somval;
var qsParm = {};
function qs() {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var parms = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i < parms.length; i++) {
        var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
        if (pos > 0) {
            var key = parms[i].substring(0, pos);
            var val = parms[i].substring(pos + 1);
            qsParm[key] = val;
            if(key == 'someval'){
            somval = val;
            }
        }
    }
}


function compare(){
    if(somval == 1){
        alert(1);
        $("#radio_1").prop("checked", true);
    }else if(somval == 2){
        alert(2);
        $("#radio_2").prop("checked", true);
    };
}
compare();
</script>
```

You can also use the below code to extract query string value for any key.
in that case the function to extract query string values is incorrect. Try using the following function to extract query string params.
The function accepts any url. If no url is passed then it takes the current url of the page.

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) {
            url = window.location.href;
        }
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        const regex = new RegExp(`[?&]${name}(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)`);
        const results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!results[2]) {
            return '';
        }
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
```

Comment: It does eliminate the error, but somval itill empty.